# angularCompiler.getNextProgram is not a function, angular 12 & custom-webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular12

I've just update my angular 11 project to 12.
I'm using `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` package in my `devDependencies` and using the following command to build my angular project.

```
ng build --configuration=production --build-optimizer --optimization
```

but after updating to angular 12, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-builders/custom-webpack/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: angularCompiler.getNextProgram is not a function
    at D:\Sources\******\Apps\******-Angular\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:390:61
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
 @ multi ./src/main.ts main[0]
```

I'm using the following package:

```
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^11.1.1"
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20778#issuecomment-841151098

Comment: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/981

Comment: Your issue should be solved by taken the actions outlined in issue [#20786](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20786).  Make sure `@angular-devkit/build-angular` is the correct version.  In my case I removed `webpack` from the devDependencies, and I installed `webpack-cli` instead.  See the post for a full discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was gone with installing version 12 of `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`
nowadays `12.0.0-beta.0`

```
@angular-builders/custom-webpack@12.0.0-beta.0
```